# How to update order details after make payment from paypal?

Tags: magento, events, paypal, magento-1.7, paypal-ipn

I am using magento 1.7 version and having issues while updating data of order after make payment from paypal.

I have a event **sales_order_invoice_pay** which works on the invoice generated. When I make a payment from paypal. Paypal generates a invoice of the placed order then this event calls.

```
<sales_order_invoice_pay>
      <observers>
          <test>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>test/observer</class>
              <method>getInvoice</method>
           </test>
       </observers>        
</sales_order_invoice_pay>
```

Then, I have a field in **sales_flat_order** table which I want to update using:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orders->setFieldId($fieldId);
```

I have value of both `$orderId` and `$fieldId`.

But it is not updating. It shows blank. I think this is due to paypal ipn which overwrites the value of my field.

**Is there any event for updating this value?**

**Any event which triggers after paypal ipn is received?**

**Any event which triggers after order detail email is sent to customer?**

**Any idea on how to solve the above issues?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override your ipn.php model file in your local pool. and put a custom event after success email send code.
at that point paypal finish with their IPN. So your code can run.